# Ubuntu thinks bash script is perl

Tags: bash, perl, ubuntu

Saving the following code into a file, Ubuntu 14.04 correctly realises that it is bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '{print $1 $2}' my_file
```

However trivially adding an instruction to awk about output formatting:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk 'BEGIN {ORS=" "} {print $1 $2}' my_file
```

Ubuntu now thinks this is Perl, as can be seen in the file properties and how gedit formats the code. What on earth is going on? (What I really care about is a much longer piece of bash code than this toy example.)

**Edit:**
Saving it with extension `.bash` was what fooled Nautilus...

Comment: That's an issue with gedit, not ubuntu. If you execute that, the system will correctly see it as bash since you told it to use bash in #!. the only glitch is from your editor confusing the syntax. In some editors you can just tell it what syntax highlighting to use for a file that it's confused about. If gedit doesn't let you change that, look for an editor that can do that job. It's about what syntax highlighting file is being used for the document, nothing more. Try another code editor and see if it has the same issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using a static shebang?

```
#!/bin/bash
```

The `env` version of shebang is more flexible, but it can possibly baffle some programs (like `gedit`)...

However, it's not an O.S. problem: if you try this command:

```
$ file myscript
myscript: a /usr/bin/env bash script text executable
```

And also `vim` correctly colors syntax...

So the issue probably is just with gedit... :-(

**UPDATE**:
As a result of the chat with OP, the issue is with the name of the script (`script.bash`).
Changing it to `script.sh` solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks, the shebang makes no difference; I also get that the `file` command thinks it's bash, but right-clicking on the file and selecting Properties, Type is 'Perl script (application/x-perl)'. That's nothing to do with gedit, right?

Comment: Right. But which file manager are you using? It's probably it's responsibility... Even if it's very strange... It is possible that some programs (`gedit`, `file-manager-x`, ...) do not use shebang to determine the file type, but use internal euristic algorithms... And your program, being one line short, and only containing awk code, which uses perl-like syntax, can confound those algorithms... I suppose it will not happen for longer bash programs, when some shell constructs are used... :-)

Comment: I don't know - just default Ubuntu file viewing - a bit of googling suggests that means Nautilus?

Comment: Yes, Nautilus is currently the default Ubuntu desktop file manager. Try adding more lines to your script... ;-)

Comment: A thousand-line bash script full of interesting bash syntax has the same problem - I reduced it to this one-liner for the sake of the example. But I've just discovered that at least I can tell gedit it's not the language it (and Nautilus) think it is via View > Highlight Mode.

Comment: What is the name of your script?

Comment: CodeSnippets.bash. You would have thought that between the extension and the shebang Nautilus would do the obvious thing...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123415/discussion-between-marcos-and-chrisw).